# How may i convert minutes "00:15" into hours in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have send the value as "00:15" in database.But its in string.So I converted into time but i'm getting error while doing so.

I used

```
("00:15".to_time) / 1.hours
```

but its giving error as

```
"NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for 2017-02-16 00:15:00 +0530:Time"
```

So i need to convert minutes into hours and update it into database so i get value as 15mins = 0.25 hrs

Comment: Where does the string `"00:15"` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do division on a string, you need to convert it to an integer before doing the calculation. Dividing by a float automatically converts it to a float so you get the decimal places; if you divided by 60 you would get `0`

```
("00:15".to_time.strftime('%M').to_i / 60.00)
```

Comment: You can use `min` instead of `strftime('%M').to_i`. However, your approach ignores the hour value, i.e. `"01:15"` would also return `0.25`.

Answer (score 3):

According to Stefan's comment I would suggest the following method:

```
time = "02:15" #or whatever time you want
time.to_time.hour + time.to_time.min / 60.00 #results in 2.25
```

The hour methods returns the hour part of a given time object, the min methods returns only the minute part of a time object.

The right part of the addition in the second line converts the minute part into the decimal part of an hour.

Comment: @MaheshSharma the two answers give different results.